# Part Identification, Board says C32 but it looks nothing like a capacitor and has 6/9 marking on it

Tags: capacitor, diodes, components, surface-mount, semiconductors

[image]First, I understand that you have to remove the components to fault find but this is just something to play with.

It's an internal HDD SATA adapter to USB3 with additional 12VDC for 3.5" HDDS. It worked for a day but then it failed. Now from what I can tell a short cct exists with the additional 12VDC cct. Doing a quick continuity and I get 0 ohms between +12V rail and negative rail.  Power pack has 12VDC, plug it into adapter no 12VDC.

The 12VDC seems to be straight through but with a few capacitors and I think the one 'C32' may be at fault. The problem is it doesn't look like a capacitor and has the markings '6/9'

Any ideas what it is or what I could replace it with .

Comment: I don't think it's actually directly parallel with the caps (i.e. your captions in the pic). The silkscreen is hiding a break in the copper.   Anyhow...what it is I don't know for sure but it could be a snubbed that has failed short.   If you remove it your device may work

Answer (score 3):

It's probably a 6uF/9V tantalum electrolytic capacitor. They don't usually go quietly so I suspect it's okay.

The end with the white line is the positive end. Photo from [here](http://www.cinetech.com.tw/index.php?action=prodtype&pt_id=3)

[image]

Comment: And it could be reading short because it's in parallel with something that *should* read short (i.e., an inductor), or -- more likely -- it's in parallel with some part that used to be made of a semiconductor, and is now made of conductive slag.

Comment: @TimWescott The latter is most certainly my guess.

Comment: Just my 2 cents.    1)  it's way too small to be a tantalum cap of that value.  2)  9uF is not a standard cap value. 3)  I think the 'white line' is a trick of the photo and it does not have a white line...that looks like the edge of the package to me.   Perhaps this is a 6V zener???   Or 'was' a 6 V zener

Comment: @KyleB Well, it could be, but "C32" is a hint that it may not be. Those are relatively large parts- 0805 probably so easily that capacity is possible. The non-standard marking is a stronger argument, so an open mind is useful.

Comment: I'll list answer as best:
TimWescot, I agree, however I thought I would ask for all knowledge before I do my damage, smd's.
Spehro and Kyle, yep the 'white line' is a trick of the photo. Only markings 6/9.
From what I can tell it's across the straight through 12V rail from the power pack. So a 6v zenner? unless it may be a hidden track to parallel boost the USB's 5v rail as for the 6uF  9V capacitor theory the 12VDC input would blow it unless it's a manufacturing fault that's why the adapter only worked for a day. 
Any other ideas before I do my damage.